# Jascript removes value of Joi class

Tags: javascript, typescript, joi

I'm using Typescript and have this, I'm trying to create Joi validation object.

Example input :

```
{
    key: 'name',
    validate: Joi.required().options({
      language: {
        any: {
          required: 'is required'
        },
        string: {
          min: 'must be at least 3 Characters'
        },
      },
    }),
 }
```

And a method :

```
 getObjects(inputs: Array<Input>) {
    const newObject = {};
    inputs.forEach(input => {
      newObject[input.key] = input.validate;
    });

    return newObject;
  }
```

But when checking `newObject`, it's only keys, and validation is `undefined`.

I realise this has something to do with the loop because this works.

```
newObject[inputs[0].key] = inputs[0].validate;
newObject[inputs[1].key] = inputs[1].validate;
```

Comment: How are you calling `getObjects`? I suspect you are passing an object instead of an array of objects. That would cause the behavior described.

Comment: If your `inputs` argument is an array with objects similar to what you've shown in the first code snippet, I don't see anything wrong with it and this should work.

Comment: @AluanHaddad like `const schema = Joi.object().keys(this.getObjects(group.inputs));`

Comment: @goto1 please see last edit.

Comment: @Relm what exactly are you passing to `getObjects`? Show us what `group.inputs` looks like.